# Sylius CartBundle : No identifier/primary key specified for Entity

Tags: symfony, cart, sylius

I am following the process described here :

http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusCartBundle/installation.html#creating-your-entities

I've been trying to implement the `CartBundle` for days without success, any help is appreciate !

I am just trying to implement my own Product Entity, as described in the doc.

Here is my YAML :

```
Pharmacie\FrontBundle\Entity\CartItem:
type: entity
table: cart_item
manyToOne:
    product:
        targetEntity: Product    
        joinColumn:
            name: product_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

The database automatically created looks good, with a ID auto increment, a `product_id` and all the fields from `sylius_cart_item`

But When I try to access :

```
/cart/add?productId=3
```

I get

> No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Pharmacie\FrontBundle\Entity\CartItem" sub class of "Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Model\CartItem". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.

Even that in the database the primary key has been set.

- Attributes `$id` and `$product` are protected in the Entity `CartItem`.
- if I have try to specify an id in the YAML i get errors saying that it's duplicate. Plus in the doc it's specify to not map id again

UPDATE : 
Maybe i went in the wrong direction.

The first error showing was :

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'Pharmacie\FrontBundle\Entity\CartItem#produit' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Pharmacie\FrontBundle\Entity\Product@000000007ba4ab6a0000000010e955d1. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Pharmacie\FrontBundle\Entity\Product#__toString()' to get a clue.
>   500 Internal Server Error - ORMInvalidArgumentException

So I added

```
$this->entityManager->persist($item);
```

And this gave me the error. But maybe i should do something different

Answer (score 0):

Your entity file should look like it:

```
Pharmacie\FrontBundle\Entity\CartItem:
    type: entity
    table: cart_item
    id:
         id:
              type: integer
              generator:
                  strategy: AUTO
    manyToOne:
        product:
            targetEntity: Product    
            joinColumn:
                name: product_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: If i use this i get : Duplicate definition of column 'id' on entity 'Pharmacie\FrontBundle\Entity
  \CartItem' in a field or discriminator column mapping. This is why i'm block